# How many and which references to own publications should be included in a research statement for post doc position?

Tags: citations, application, research-statement

I am composing my research statement for post doc applications in astrophysics/cosmology. I found that if I cite all the work associated with my work, then the references itself are taking around 2.5 pages. Some of the job applications have a restriction on the length of the research statement including the references. In such cases, do I not cite all the references? How do I pick which reference to keep and which one to ignore?

Comment: Interesting question, but I dont think there will be a generally applicable, optimal number of references to include.

Comment: Footnote: "Citations refer to publications listed in my CV."

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best if you cite a small number of most relevant work. Readers from your field will probably get an idea from a limited bibliography. You can perhaps provide with a link to a page that you set as an extended version of bibliography related to your work. If page limit is an issue you can explore various alternative citation styles which might be more compact and save you space. One example is to use just the name of first author followed by *et al*.